# Removing ./ with browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify, require

I'm on a windows machine and I'm using browserify and gulp.

I want to remove the ./ in my require statements, is this possible?

Example:

Instead of require('./config.js'); I want it to be require('config.js');

My gulp file currently looks like this:

```
gulp.src('client/app.js')
  .pipe(browserify({
      paths: ['./node_modules', './client']
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('website/public/js'))
  .on('error', function (error) {
    console.error('' + error);
});
```

If I try to compile the code:

var clientConfig = require('config.js');

then the result is literally "var clientConfig = require('config.js');" which isn't correct since it's supposed to include the contents.

If I use var clientConfig = require('./config.js'); then it works. Is there anyway to remove the ./ or is it required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the [pathmodify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pathmodify) browserify plugin.